# From $(1+z)^p(1+z)^q=(1+z)^{p+q}$ show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^r\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}=\binom{p+q}{r}$ without using the Cauchy product

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm stuck on what was an easy exercise at first sight. It's exercise 18, PSet 15.3, Kreyszig "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" 10th ed. It asks to prove that given $(1+z)^p(1+z)^q=(1+z)^{p+q}$ then  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^r\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}=\binom{p+q}{r}$.

Taking for granted that $(1+z)^p=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k} z^k$ and from

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n} z^n \sum\limits_{m=0}^q\binom{q}{m} z^m=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{p+q}\binom{p+q}{r} z^r$$

I should be able to manipulate the indices to get $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{p+q}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{r}\binom{p}{n} \binom{q}{r-n}z^r$ but I can't. My attempt was noticing that there is a constraint for which $n+m=r$ and $m,n>0$:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n} z^n \sum\limits_{m=0}^q\binom{q}{m} z^m=\sum\limits_{n=0}^p\sum\limits_{m=0}^q\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{m} z^{n+m}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^p\sum\limits_{r=n}^{q+n}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n} z^r=\\
=\sum\limits_{r=n}^{q+n}\sum\limits_{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n} z^r$$

This is the closest I can get to $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{p+q}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{r}\binom{p}{n} \binom{q}{r-n}z^r$. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: This question is already answered. You might find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516782/binomial-theorem-proof/2516850#2516850)* helpful.

Comment: Compare the coefficients of $$x^r$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I compared the coefficients. I listed r=0, so n=0 m=0; r=1, so n=0 m=1, n=1 m=0, but I can compare just few. How to be sure it holds for any r. I tried induction but it seemed difficult to do, beyond the scope of the exercise, maybe I missed something.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer in the answer you linked the answer is built using the Cauchy product. Maybe I'm wrong, but with the Cauchy product there is nothing to prove, so I thought I didn't have to use that.

Comment: @the_eraser: A multiplication of two series of this kind does always use the Cauchy product. There's nothing wrong in using it. It *is* that simple. :-)

Comment: Edit: I added "without using the Cauchy product" to the title to make more explicit that this was my original intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The transformations are fine up to
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^p\sum_{r=n}^{q+n}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}z^r\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

But note the representation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=n}^{q+n}\sum_{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}z^r
\end{align*}
is *not valid*, since the index $r$ in the outer sum starts with $r=n$, but $n$ is not defined. The *scope* of the inner index $n$ does not extend to the outer sum.

> Nevertheless we can derive the following continuing with (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^p\sum_{r=n}^{q+n}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}z^r
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{p+q}\sum_{r=n}^{p+q}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}z^r\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq n\leq r\leq p+q}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}z^r\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{p+q}\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{r}\binom{p}{n}\binom{q}{r-n}}z^r\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>   which is the representation we are looking for. Comparison of coefficients with
>   \begin{align*}
> (1+z)^{p+q}=\sum_{r=0}^{p+q}\color{blue}{\binom{p+q}{r}}z^r
> \end{align*}
>   shows the wanted result (without using the Cauchy product formula).

*Comment:*

- In (2) we set the upper limit of the sums to $p+q$ by noting that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k>n$.
- In (3) we just use another presentation of the index range to better see the situation.
- In (4) we exchange the sums by respecting the range of the indices indicated in (3).

Comment: Perfect! There was something perstering me about that step, but I wasn't realizing what was wrong. Thank you very much! Also very good formatting, next time I'll try to emulate you.

Comment: @the_eraser: You're welcome! Thanks for your nice comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-What you need is just the well known product of polynomials

$$(a_0x^p+a_1x^{p-1}+\cdots+a_{p-1}x+a_p)\cdot(b_0x^q+b_1x^{q-1}+\cdots+b_{q-1}x+b_q)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p+q}c_nx^n....                                           
               (*)$$ where
$c_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}$ applied to the multiplication of two polynomials
$$\binom p0 z^p+\binom p1 z^{p-1}+\cdots+\binom {p}{p-1}z+\binom pp$$
$$\binom q0 z^q+\binom q1 z^{q-1}+\cdots+\binom {q}{q-1}z+\binom qq$$
The formule you want is just both
 $(*)$ with the obvious $(1+z)^p\cdot(1+z)^q=(1+z)^{p+q}$.

Another way is to apply induction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to take for granted that $\;(1+z)^p=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k} z^k$ : it's the definition of binomial coefficients.

Just wonder how one can obtain a term of degree $r$ from $\;\displaystyle\sum _{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n} z^n\cdot \sum_{m=0}^q\binom{q}{m} z^m$ : due tio distributivity, just take a term $\;\displaystyle\binom{p}{n} z^n$ from the first factor and a term $\;\displaystyle\binom{p}{m} z^m$  so that $n+m=r$, in all possible ways, and add them. In other words:
$$\binom{p+q}rz^r=\sum_{\begin{matrix}n+m=r\\[-0.76ex]0\le n\le p\\[-0.5ex]0\le m\le q\end{matrix}}\binom{p}{n} z^n\cdot\binom{q}{m} z^m. $$
If you observe that from $n+m=r$, you deduce that $m=r-n$, you obtain readily
$$\binom{p+q}r=\sum_{n=0}^r\binom{p}{n} \binom{q}{n-r}, $$being understood that if it happens that $n>p$ or $n-r>q$, then $\dbinom pn=0\;$ or  $\dbinom q{n-r}=0$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... so my steps are all correct and then I can "extend" $r$ and "shrink" $n$ from $\sum\limits_{r=n}^{q+n}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{p}$ to $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{q+p}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{r}$ because everything I added is $0$ because of the form $\binom{q}{r-n}$ with either $r-n>q$ or $r-n<0$. Right?

Comment: It's exactly that.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer and comment has been very useful!